# Is there a way to clean up possibly invalid disks that only show up on Mac OS Recovery through ‘diskutil list’ in Terminal? Does Recovery use them?

Tags: macos, terminal, recovery, diskutil

Hopefully that question is clear enough, and hopefully this is just me being silly. When I boot into the Recovery Partition, go into Terminal, and run 'diskutil list', I get quite a few tiny and seemingly invalid disks (starting at /dev/disk2):

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.3 GB     disk1
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        1.3 GB     disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk3
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk4
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk5
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk6
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *6.3 MB     disk7
/dev/disk8
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *2.1 MB     disk8
/dev/disk9
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk9
/dev/disk10
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk10
/dev/disk11
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *524.3 KB   disk11
/dev/disk12
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               *1.0 MB     disk12
```

I ran 'diskutil info' on each of the disks and received the following output:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Volumes
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Volumes

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              C8F2576E-A234-3178-AADC-F12393BB2445

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        376.8 KB (376832 Bytes) (exactly 736 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk3
   Device Node:              /dev/disk3
   Part of Whole:            disk3
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /private/var/tmp
   Escaped with Unicode:     /private/var/tmp

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              DC4623F9-52B3-384F-8AF4-67E833986A4E

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        380.9 KB (380928 Bytes) (exactly 744 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk4
   Device Node:              /dev/disk4
   Part of Whole:            disk4
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /private/var/run
   Escaped with Unicode:     /private/var/run

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              AEED02C4-DF3A-35A7-BF6C-1291DB7DF5EA

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        364.5 KB (364544 Bytes) (exactly 712 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk5
   Device Node:              /dev/disk5
   Part of Whole:            disk5
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /System/Installation
   Escaped with Unicode:     /System/Installation

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              FA0AB5AC-4A8B-3330-890A-B08290C44B83

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        376.8 KB (376832 Bytes) (exactly 736 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk6
   Device Node:              /dev/disk6
   Part of Whole:            disk6
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /private/var/db
   Escaped with Unicode:     /private/var/db

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              21B26EE7-E7B2-310C-8ACE-AB3D85036C12

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        258.0 KB (258048 Bytes) (exactly 504 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk7
   Device Node:              /dev/disk7
   Part of Whole:            disk7
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /private/var/folders
   Escaped with Unicode:     /private/var/folders

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              57F696D8-737A-3AAD-B917-D6B010FB437F

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               6.3 MB (6291456 Bytes) (exactly 12288 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        4.5 MB (4456448 Bytes) (exactly 8704 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk8
   Device Node:              /dev/disk8
   Part of Whole:            disk8
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /private/var/root/Library
   Escaped with Unicode:     /private/var/root/Library

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              8CC74661-9E77-32D3-8C6B-85865271D5CD

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               2.1 MB (2097152 Bytes) (exactly 4096 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        1.2 MB (1228800 Bytes) (exactly 2400 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk9
   Device Node:              /dev/disk9
   Part of Whole:            disk9
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              2F53A1B0-92F3-3945-960B-82E96D9A1DA6

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               1.0 MB (1048576 Bytes) (exactly 2048 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        901.1 KB (901120 Bytes) (exactly 1760 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk10
   Device Node:              /dev/disk10
   Part of Whole:            disk10
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Library/Preferences
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Library/Preferences

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              4F7EA62F-FC30-3C29-8FFB-C1711B2AD0EC

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        356.4 KB (356352 Bytes) (exactly 696 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk11
   Device Node:              /dev/disk11
   Part of Whole:            disk11
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              22FE002E-D4B9-3405-BA81-95B03A62A222

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               524.3 KB (524288 Bytes) (exactly 1024 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        360.4 KB (360448 Bytes) (exactly 704 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
   Device Identifier:        disk12
   Device Node:              /dev/disk12
   Part of Whole:            disk12
   Device / Media Name:      Apple disk image Media

   Volume Name:              untitled
   Escaped with Unicode:     untitled

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Library/Keychains
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Library/Keychains

   File System Personality:  HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      None
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 Disk Image
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              5BB6904E-F8BD-3D1F-99A7-F37ECDE58587

   System Image:             Yes

   Total Size:               1.0 MB (1048576 Bytes) (exactly 2048 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        872.4 KB (872448 Bytes) (exactly 1704 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

=====================================================================
```

Some of the drives are mounted in familiar places (like /Volumes) and some of them are mounted in less familiar places (like /private/var). Nevertheless, I don't recall any of these drives showing up as mounted the first time I've had my Mac. Does anyone perhaps know why these disks show up and/or if I can remove them? Thanks!

Comment: Do not attempt to remove them, they're basically RAM disks and are needed for recovery mode to function. See [this previous answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22941/what-is-the-mac-os-x-base-system-disk-image-on-my-2011-macbook-air/23081#23081).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you for your very quick response! I will leave the drives alone. It was more of what seemed like an aesthetics problem.