# How to delete redundant disks on disk utility

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility, monterey, internet-recovery

I reinstalled my OS a couple of times and ended up with many redundant disks as you can see in the picture:
[image]

I want to get rid of them.

Of course, I tried the following diskutil commands:

- **eraseDisk** : the command only erases the content of the "disk" but not the disk itself.
- **mergePartitions** : tried merging all redundant partitions into one but didn't work.

*Note: I didn't use FileVault.*

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like you are in recovery or install mode, or something like that. If that's the case, those are just part of how that mode functions. See ["What is the 'Mac OS X Base System' disk image on my 2011 MacBook AIr?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22941/what-is-the-mac-os-x-base-system-disk-image-on-my-2011-macbook-air)

Comment: It is the exact same problem. A little surprised Apple didn't address this issue since then as these disks cannot be deleted from what I understand of your thread...

Comment: I'm not sure why they'd be considered a problem that needs addressing; they're a bit confusing, but other than that they're just part of what allows recovery mode to function while taking up a minimum of actual disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Posted the same question on the [Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253741550) and got the following answer:

> When you boot into Internet Recovery, the minimal system creates over
> 25 RAM-disks, of type disk-image, all modest in size, and uses them to
> hold temporary items. This leaves the boot drive completely free to be
> Repaired, Erased, or whatever needs to happen.
>
> Trying to remove them will crash Recovery.
>
> Those RAM-Disks are not permanent. Just restart into regular mode or
> Safe mode, and they will be gone.

Another answer with additional explanation:

> In that report, your "real" disk is Disk0, size about 256GB, and it
> holds a GUID partition Map, an EFI partition, and a container-disk.
>
> Synthesized inside the container-disk is disk2, which contains the
> components of your APFS drive.
>
> Look closely at the SIZES of those items.
>
> Since diskutil list is recomputed at every startup, when you start up
> without Internet recovery active, your APFS Volume will likely move to
> a different disk number.