# Two (2) macOS Base Systems?

Tags: hard-drive

I found this:

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5   233Gi   10Gi  111Gi     9%  488255 2447613065    0%   /
devfs          342Ki  342Ki    0Bi   100%    1184          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s1   233Gi  107Gi  111Gi    50% 1405058 2446696262    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s4   233Gi  4.0Gi  111Gi     4%       5 2448101315    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
/dev/disk2s1   594Mi  494Mi  101Mi    84%       6 4294967273    0%   /Volumes/RecoveryHDMeta
/dev/disk3s1   1.9Gi  1.2Gi  654Mi    66%   48034 4294919245    0%   /Volumes/macOS Base System
/dev/disk4s1   1.9Gi  1.2Gi  654Mi    66%   48034 4294919245    0%   /Volumes/macOS Base System 1
```

Is this normal? (last two lines) Can I erase `/Volumes/macOS Base System 1` and reclaim that space, or will I be breaking something?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Good to give macOS version. I prefer output of `diskutil list` as a starting point.

Comment: This looks like you're in recovery mode, in which case those are probably virtual disks of some sort, and don't take up any actual disk space, and are needed for recovery mode to function (though I don't know why there'd be two). See my answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22941/what-is-the-mac-os-x-base-system-disk-image-on-my-2011-macbook-air/23081).

Comment: You're right @Gilby! Sorry for missing that important bit! It's Catalina 10.15.7. `diskutil list` looks way prettier but I like to see percentages!

Thanks for chipping in @GordonDavisson! Your comment makes a lot of sense, however, I am not in recovery mode.

Comment: @mariano-daniel Adding the output of `diskutil list` would help clarify what's going on. Note that the volumes are listed as being on different disks (/dev/disk3 and /dev/disk4); these *might* be partitions on your disk, but my guess is that they (and probably /dev/disk2, which holds RecoveryHDMeta) are actually mounted disk images. It looks to me like something mounted your recovery system (which is a normal part of a macOS) and another recovery (not sure where that's from), and just left them mounted. Rebooting will probably remove (i.e. unmount) them.

Comment: Thank you for your help @GordonDavisson! This is the output:
```diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2 ```

Comment: ```/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     114.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 172.5 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s3```

Comment: ```4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.2 GB    disk1s5```

Comment: Also worth adding, I don't see `/Volumes/macOS Base System 1` after a reboot, so maybe it was some installation type of Volume or? Now it's a mystery I would like to solve 

Comment: @mariano-daniel I'm pretty sure it was part of a system update -- "RecoveryHDMeta" is [part of how Apple delivers updates to the recovery system](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-update-the-recovery-partition-in-high-sierra.2181484/), so it makes sense for both that and the recovery disk image (which is actually stored on disk1s3) to be mounted. The only thing that seems weird is that second "macOS Base System" recovery image (note: the "1" is just added because there are two mounted volumes with the same name).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @GordonDavisson! I agree with you, surely it was the updates, however it's quite weird that there was a second one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a system update, as pointed out by @Gordon Davisson.